# Could not run elki.sh in mac OSX

Tags: macos, elki

In order to use ELKI to do a clustering task, I have downloaded the latest complete release package: elki-0.7.1

The README.PDF says to run elki.sh on OSX. However, after I run the elki.sh with Terminal, it pops the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.ELKILauncher

I am sure I have downloaded the complete packages entirely, but still could not run ELKI successfully. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without further information, nobody will be able to help you. Is the class path set up correctly? The error reported is 100% in *Java*, not in ELKI - this is Java saying it does not find the elki classes.

Comment: Have you figured out the error? If there is an easy way to make the script work on your computer, too, I would be happy to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

I will show below how you can install Elki in macOS, El Capitan Version 10.11.6.

### **Installation of ELKI in macOS**

```
brew cask install java

git clone https://github.com/elki-project/elki.git

cd elki

./gradlew shadowJar

./gradlew build

open elki-bundle-0.7.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

[image]

where you can see the ELKILauncher.

### **Example that ELKI is working just fine**

[image]

[image]

[image]

### **Background**

> [image]
>
> You don't have to configure any paths, actually. Questions you may want to ask yourself are
>
> - Did you build the Elki on the command line?
> - Do you have the correct Java? You can install it easiest with `brew` as shown above.

Comment: You are recompiling the "elki bundle"; but the shell script is for the approach where you can drop extension .jars into the dependency folder. So you don't solve the underlying problem.
Of course, getting the latest source code and compiling yourself is generally a *good* idea, rather than relying on a .jar file; so I would usually suggest to get the source and compile yourself, so you can modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the single-jar, you should simply be able to run the jar without the script. Or you could clone the git project in Eclipse and run it.
Make sure you have the path names correct, and try using `bash` to run the script. OSX choices are sometimes a bit odd. Open the script in an editor, and adjust it to your needs (it's a *script*)